# ibus - Difference between Input Method and Input Sources

Tags: kali-linux, gnome3, input-method, gsettings, ibus

Currently if i press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, gnome desktop will pop up 2 language selections set by **Input Sources** from `gnome-control-center`. Then why not it pop up 3 languages selection set by **Input Method** section from `ibus-setup` instead ?

[image]

What's the difference between both ?

My platform is Kali Linux 2016.2, GNOME Shell 3.22.0, and IBus 1.5.11.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that only **Input Source** from `gnome-control-center` affects the input

Also, not all input sources that appear actually work, e.g. `cangjie3`, `cangjie5`, `cangjie-big` don't work for me, only `cangjie (mn17n)` worked for me.

Hence, if your `Intelligent Pinyin` didn't work for you, try using `GooglePinyin` which worked for me.

For the `ibus-preferences`, I was still able to use my `cangjie (mn17n)` even if there was nothing in Input Methods